# Redirecting Requests to https breaks Stripe webhook

Tags: nginx, stripe-payments

I recently modified my nginx server to redirect all `www.mysite` requests to `https://mysite`

The problem is that when I did that, my stripe webhook I had set up is now failing with a 301 redirect error. How do I alter my nginx server to that only requests coming from my domain are redirected? (or at least I think that's the solution, I'm a front end guy).

Here's my server.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/app/mysite;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mykey.key;

    #enables SSLv3/TLSv1, but not SSLv2 which is weak and should no longer be used.
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #Disables all weak ciphers
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;


    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mysite.com;
  return 301 https://mysite.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mpcabd mentioned, Stripe webhooks will not follow redirects for security reasons. As he also mentioned, while you *can* filter by IP, it's a never-ending battle (and Stripe has previously stated they do intend to eventually stop publishing an IP list).

The even easier and better set-it-and-forget-it solution:

In the [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/), reconfigure your webhooks to use HTTPS.

Bam. Done.

Comment: Oh my I'm an idiot for not thinking of that! haha thanks man!

Comment: Often it's the obvious stuff that gets overlooked. ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to exclude Stripe from the redirect, I think their hook doesn't follow redirects for security reasons which is fair, so try to see what IP's they use and make sure you don't redirect if the `$http_x_real_ip` or `$remote_addr` is from Strip's IP list.

But as clearly stated [here](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/IcezRRZP0bw) by Stripe:

> ... because we occasionally have to adjust this list of IP 
>   addresses without any advance notice, we strongly recommend against 
>   using IP-based access control to protect your webhook endpoints. 
>   Instead, we recommend serving your webhook endpoint over SSL, 
>   embedding a secret identifier in the webhook URL that is only known to 
>   you and Stripe, and/or retrieving the event by ID from our API ...

So my answer would be to **check if the location requested is the Stripe webhook, then serve it without a redirect, else redirect the request**.

Answer (score 0):

Please concatenates the intermediate certificate with your signed SSL certificate.

Ref :
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-ssl-certifcate-chain